# Youtube API playing next video if else statement

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

Using the iframe youtube API I'd like this if else statement to play a certain random video off this playlist given the number chosen. As of now it seems to give me some repeating videos not based on the random number generated.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player(
    'player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: {},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'nextVideo': nextVideo,
      }
    });
  }
  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {   
  player.loadPlaylist({
                 list: 'mozart',
                 listType:'search',
               })   
  event.target.playVideo();
  } 

  function nextVideo() {
  var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log(num);

  if (num >= 2) {
  player.nextVideo();
  player.loadPlaylist({
                 list: '90s rap',
                 listType: 'search',
               })   
   player.setShuffle(true);
   player.playVideo();

  }

  else if (num < 2) {
    player.nextVideo();
   player.loadPlaylist({
                 list: 'mozart',
                 listType:'search',
               })   
 player.setShuffle(true);
 player.playVideo();
  }
  else {}

  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

and here is the html

```
<a href="javascript:nextVideo()" id="next">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few questionable things you're doing in your code.

In general, you shouldn't be calling `loadPlaylist()` + `setShuffle()` + `playVideo()` repeatedly in your code. I'd recommend calling `loadPlaylist()` + `setShuffle()` once at the start, and then whenever you want to play a "random" video, just call `nextVideo()`. Because the playlist is already shuffled, the next video will effectively be random.